# Laravel Sanctum tokens() undefined

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

i'm new to laravel and trying to build an api for a login using sanctum.

I followed documentation, and a few tutorials but i've encountered an error where the token function is not accessible by my user class even when using HasApiToken.

here is my user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'alt_id',
        'country_id',
        'birth'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'type',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Country::class);
    }
}
```

[this is the error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzGK9.png

I also already checked the route in config/auth.php and it is App\Models\User::class

Comment: That's just an Intelephense message. Does the code work if you access the site? Or is there an error message?

Comment: I... didn't try to run it, i assumed it would not let me, just did and it does work.
no idea how to remove the false error alert, but if it works it doesn't really matter.

Comment: That sometimes happen if you don't have the right or outdated plugins. Intelephense is mostly correct but you shouldn't blindly rely on it :)

Answer (score 4):

I've solved that problem by adding `$user->tokens()->delete();` into my AuthController@logout,

```html
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
  public function logout(User $user){

          $user->tokens()->delete();

          return [
              'message' => 'Logged out'
          ];
      }
 }
```

And User model looks like this.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        //some code
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        //some code
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        //some code
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Admit your comment and Edit my Ans to a more readable format. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Great. Enjoy StackOverflow! :-)